# Ejabberd Server responding with error 10, you are not authorized to call this command

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying to hit the endpoint /register on my ejabberd server

i am getting the following error  -

```
{ status: 'error',
  code: 10,
  message: 'You are not authorized to call this command.' }
```

The api_permissions section is as follows

```
 api_permissions:
"console commands":
from:
  - ejabberd_ctl
  - mod_http_api
who: all
what: "*"
"admin access":
who:
  - access:
      - allow:
          - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
          - acl: admin
  - oauth:
    - scope: "ejabberd:admin"
    - access:
      - allow:
          - ip: "127.0.0.1/8"
          - acl: admin
what:
  - "*"
  - "!stop"
  - "!start"
"public commands":
who: all
what:
  - "status"
  - "connected_users_number"
```

I am sending username and password in the auth request part of my header. The username is registered under the acl part of my ejabberd.yml file like so

```
admin:
   user:
     - "testuser@internal_ip_address"
```

N:B: I am sending the post request to http://127.0.0.1:5280/api/register from a nodejs script. I am getting the 'status connected' when i hit the .../api/status endpoint.

i have tried twicking my ejabberd.yml file and i still get that error. not sure how to give my user the right permissions to access the endpoint

Answer (score 1):

In this section add:

- "public commands":

  - who: all
  - what:

    - "status"
    - "connected_users_number"
    - **"register"**

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issues:.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62714012/strophe-disconnecting-from-ejabbered-with-status-10